# Unrealistic RSSI of 0 dBm for some scanned wifi networks

Tags: macos, terminal, network, wifi, command-line

If I scan for wifi networks in Terminal with `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/A/Resources/airport -s` I noticed some networks that are shown with a very high RSSI of 0 dBm. Since these devices disappear from time to time and sometimes also reappear with a value of -75 to -88 I assume this must be an error. Should I ignore these networks or is there any reason why they have this high RSSI value? I couldn't find any clues in the help text for the airport command.